# How can I play multiple audio files in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, audio

I get an Excel report that contains a column of links to audio files that I need to listen to.  I have to click on the link in the cell, it links to and downloads the file, I click open and I hear the audio which usually lasts between 2 and 5 seconds.  It is tedious to click on each one, but when I select the range of cells, I am unable to link to and download all the files together.  Is there any way I can select all of them to play one after the other?

Answer (score 0):

A tedious solution would be to create an html page with the list of links to the audio files, download them all, and join them together using Windows Movie Maker, or another audio program.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I see how creating a page of links would help me if I already have a list of links.